# Correct usage of the words  "blow" and "fit"

Tags: word-usage

Does the following sentence have correct use of the word 'blow' and 'fit' ? (separate sentences)

> A sudden gust of wind made the candles blow off.
>
> I'm very busy, I had to fit ten appointments in one morning

Comment: Please ask separate questions, the two words are really not related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Re the first sentence:**

I would say "blow out" for what candles do in the wind.  I believe that "blow off" can be slang for releasing gas from one's bottom.

**Re the second sentence:**

Your use of "fit" is fine, but I would probably write "into one morning" rather than "in one morning".  Also, the comma should be a semi-colon, as the two parts of the sentence are grammatically independent of one another.

Comment: On the other hand, the candles might have been blown off the cake.

Comment: Oh, yes, I suppose they could have.  @vinoth - can you please clarify whether you meant that the candles blew right off the cake; or whether you meant that they were simply extinguished?

Comment: @David , these were questions in GMAT question paper. We may never know what they meant :)